# having multiple quorum queues and regular(classic) queues the same time

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit, quorum

In RabbitMQ clustering, can we have multiple queues with quorum type and multiple other queues with regular(classic) type at the same time? if yes, then with Masstransit, how can I register some of them with quorum and others of them with regular(classic) type?

I wrote the below code. but this code applies to all queues:

```
public class ConfigureQuorumReceiveEndpoint: IConfigureReceiveEndpoint
{
    private const string QueueType = "x-queue-type";
    private const string QuorumQueue = "quorum";
    public void Configure(string name, IReceiveEndpointConfigurator configurator)
    {
        if (configurator is IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator rabbitMqConfigurator)
        {
            rabbitMqConfigurator.SetQueueArgument(QueueType, QuorumQueue);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I apply it to some specific queues?

Answer (score 1):

The `name` parameter is the receive endpoint name (queue) - you can use that to determine if you want that queue to be Quorum or not.

Comment: thanks, I just registered the above code. but how can I pass the name parameter?

Comment: The name is a parameter for the Configure method, it's provided by MassTransit when that method is called.